# How do you identify a deuteragonist, tritagonist, etc

Tags: meaning

Forgive this probably simple question, but I have just recently come across the terms deuteragonist, tritagonist, and others like them. Do they refer to main characters or secondary characters, and how would you identify a character as being one of these terms?

For example, if we are looking at "The Lord of the Flies", would Piggy be the deuteragonist, since he is the second most prominent character in the book? And, by that logic, could you say Simon is the tritagonist?

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: What makes you think that the dictionary is wrong?

Comment: Welcome to EL&U. This site is more about the mechanics of the language; literary analysis is not on-topic here. We do have a sister site, [Literature.SE](https://literature.stackexchange.com/), currently in development, that may be better-equipped to answer, but they are not yet open to the public.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it might be better answered on Literature.SE